# Unable to create multiple pull request from same branch; new commits always added to first PR

Tags: git, github

I recently created a "testBranch" branch in one of my GitHub repositories to address multiple issues and create separate pull requests for each of them. I thought that I'd be able to address each issue in separate commits on "testBranch", and then create a PR for each commit linked to that issues. I am unable to do this.

### what I did

1. I created a branch, `testBranch`.
2. I committed some changes on `testBranch` to address one of the issues
3. I created a pull request for that commit and linked the issue to it.
4. I made a new commit on `testBranch` to address the next issue.
5. Usually after making a commit, I know that GitHub would check if there are any changes before permitting you to create a PR, but when I click "New Pull Request", this is what shows:

   [image: screenshot of what I see on the GitHub page]

   The second commit which I made shows at the bottom, below the `Update README.md` commit. I see "View Pull Request" on the right.

I thought GitHub would compare the changes from the second commit and then let me create a new PR from it. Since I was unable to do that, I resorted to creating multiple branches, one for each individual PR.

I want all this to happen inside one branch, `testBranch`. How do I do that?

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong: you created MR, and it has 2 commits in it, and this is exactly what you wanted, no? If I got something wrong - please be a bit more elaborate. When you create MR, normally it is pre-filled with whatever details from the last commit, so hence the duplicated *Update README.md* message left from *View pull request* button. You just need to update the MR description, but it looks like you did create MR. Perhaps other might correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Loni, i think I know what is going on, but before I do that, please update your question making it very clear each of the steps you did. Otherwise I'm not excactly sure what you did, but can only guess. Please do that in the question, not in the comments below (and you can delete your above comment once you do that).

Comment: Alright @Inigo. Let me do that.

Comment: Loni, you had 2 steps and then said, "That was basically it". But then had many paragraphs after that where you did more, so it was confusing. I moved all of your actions into the list of steps, to make it clear and remove a lot of repetition. This is what you wan to go for in future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create two different open pull requests from the same branch. The branch is already the subject of a pull request. That is why GitHub offers to show you the pull request. You cannot create it; you have already created it.

Further commits on the same branch will be appended to the existing pull request.

Alternatives:

- After the pull request is merged, you can add more commits and push to make a new pull request.
- Or, create a new branch from your pull request branch, add commits to it, and push it to have two pull requests open simultaneously.

Comment: There is one caveat to alternative #2: If a later PR is merged before an earlier on, it will end up including the commits from the earlier PR because "create a new branch from your pull request branch" results in the second branch having all the commits from the first PR. If you concur, matt, I can edit your answer with clarification.

Comment: @Inigo Seems to me that that changes the subject (management of multiple PRs when one is based on another). If you want, how about giving your own answer about that? But it seems to me that we've dealt with this before; if we can find a canonical QA, a link would be sufficient.

Comment: that was my point. you alternative #2 is for "management of multiple PRs when one is based on another". I just think that should be made clear since you did provide an answer rather than mark the question as a duplicate.